# Basis of Q$(\sqrt[4]{3})$/Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I want to show that Q$(\sqrt[4]{3})$/Q is algebraic. I am pretty sure that {1, $(\sqrt[4]{3})$} is a basis of this extension, and I was wondering if in general, for a (some irrational number) and the field extension Q(a)/Q, the basis is {1, a}.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not true. Note you cannot  express $(\sqrt[4]{3}))^3$ as a linear combination of $1$ and $\sqrt[4]{3}$.

The degree of the extension is $4$; so you need four elements.

Comment: Oh right... Silly of me. Thank you quid.

Comment: I was wondering, how do you show the degree of the extension is 4 without explicitly computing the minimal polynomial?

Comment: In some sense one has to know the minimal polynomial. But also the degree of $\sqrt[n]{p}$ for prime $p$ is always $n$, as $x^n -p$ is irreducible and thus the min polynomial. So, one can also 'just know' it. But implicitly it is still the min poly there.

Comment: It's easy to see that $x^4 - 3$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, by Eisenstein.

Comment: I was looking for the solution of a+b $\sqrt[4]{3}$, is that not necessary?

Comment: @jstnchng If you know that $x^4 - 3$ is irreducible (which one can know by Eisenstein as David said) then it follow thst $1, \sqrt[4]{3}, \sqrt[4]{3}^2, \sqrt[4]{3}^3$ is independent as otherwise you could built a polynomial of lower than degree 4 that has $\sqrt[4]{3}$ as a root, which is not possible.

Comment: Look, let $\alpha$ be any fourth root of $3$ in the complex numbers. Then $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3\}$ is a linearly independent set over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! I think I understand it now.